# Parâmetro FieldByName negrito

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, report-builder

Olá, tenho um RichText que fiz a inserção do texto via programação, porém tem algumas partes desse texto que trago do banco, preciso que esses campos específicos fiquem em negrito dentro do RichText.

Segue um exemplo do código.

```
Texto1.RichText:='A Diretora da Escola teste no uso de suas atribuições e tendo em vista a conclusão do '
                + 'Periodo I'+ ' do Curso ' + pipMestre['NOME_CURSO'] 
                + ', Eixo Tecnológico ' + reconhecimento.FieldByName('eixo') 
                + ', confere o Título de ' + 'a';
```

Precisaria que o FieldByName ficasse em negrito.

Agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 2):

Para colocar parte do texto em negrito utilizando o `RichEdit` (não tenho o componente `RichText`), temos que selecionar a palavra que desejamos colocar em negrito dentro do texto. Para isso precisamos encontra-la.

Então criei uma função que você passa o `RichEdit` e o texto que deseja colocar em negrito para que seja aplicado.

```
procedure TForm1.textoNegrito(ARichEdit: TRichEdit; ATexto: String);
var
  iPosIni : integer;
begin
    ARichEdit.SelStart  := 0;
    ARichEdit.SelLength := length(ARichEdit.Text);

    //Encontra e atribui a posição inicial do texto no RichEdit
    iPosIni := ARichEdit.FindText(ATexto, 0, length(ARichEdit.Text), []);

    //Verifica se o texto foi encontrado
    if iPosIni >= 0 then
    begin
        ARichEdit.SelStart  := iPosIni;
        ARichEdit.SelLength := length(ATexto);
        // Aplica o negrito
        ARichEdit.SelAttributes.style := [fsBold];
    end;
end;
```

Sua utilização seria algo como:

```
...
var
  vlA,vlB : string;
begin
  vlA :=  'teste 1';
  vlB :=  'teste 2';

  Texto1.Text := 'A Diretora da Escola teste no uso de suas atribuições e tendo em vista a conclusão do '
                + 'Periodo I'+ ' do Curso ' + vlA
                + ', Eixo Tecnológico ' + vlB
                + ', confere o Título de ' + 'a';

  textoNegrito(Texto1,vlA);
...
```

<sub>*Referência utilizada: https://www.devmedia.com.br/pesquisando-e-destacando-texto-no-richedit/24260*</sub>